# Cache image for collection view which inside table view

Tags: swift, uitableview, caching

I have collection view with horizontal scroll inside table view.

When I scroll down, I see some flickering image inside it. I decided to use the cache `NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()`, to save all my images and prevent downloading all the time from server. But I still have the same problem.

Do you have any ideas how to fix that?

[image]

Comment: I would recommend using Kingfisher for image caching, it is super easy to use and it handles everything: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher It's the one I always use when it comes to image caching and performance loading.

Comment: can i see the code?